# How can i get single value instead of object using v-select

Tags: vue.js, frontend, v-select

i am trying to bind a list of objects in v-select autocomplete using below code

```
<v-select
   label="name"
   id="auto_assign"
   name="auto_assign"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
   :filterable="false"
   :options="itemsAutoAssign"
   v-model="params.requester_id"
   @search="getItemsAutoAssign">
      <template slot="no-options"> Type to search </template>
</v-select>
```

itemsAutoAssign has a structure like this

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'iman1', mobile: '+989188455223'},
   {id: 2, name: 'iman2', mobile: '+989188455224'},
   {id: 3, name: 'iman3', mobile: '+989188455225'},
]
```

but after changing value, the `params.requester_id` value is an object. I need just id not whole object.
I can change the value in my submit button but i need a best practice and true way.

Answer (score 1):

Changes the options to

`:items="itemsAutoAssign"`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the text and value of v-select using `item-text` and `item-value`. For more information, please refer [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#custom-text-and-value).

Nonetheless, your code seems to be correct except v-select doesn't have `options`  property. It should be `items` instead.

Comment: after i apply changes in my code, It shows options without any label.